# Using jQuery to test if the user has typed in an input?

Tags: jquery

I have a variable called `$places`:

```
    var $places = $('#resultsListing li.place');
```

When there are more than 0 `places` the following code add the class `.have-results`. If there are 0 results the code adds the class `.no-results` to the body:

```
body.removeClass("have-results no-results searching");

body.addClass(places.length > 0 ? "have-results" : "no-results");
$("div#busyAnimation").hide();
```

I would like to add another class called `.hasnt-typed-yet`. I know it is a horrible name for a class, but that's what I want to accomplish; add that class to the body if the user hasn't typed yet in the input.

Any suggestions to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var textbox_text = $("#searchbox").val(); 
if(textbox_text !== '' ){
    body.addClass(places.length > 0 ? "have-results" : "no-results");
}else{
   body.addClass('hasnt-typed-yet');
}
$("div#busyAnimation").hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if($('input').val() == '')
    $('body:first').addClass('hasnt-typed-yet')
else
    $('body:first').removeClass('hasnt-typed-yet')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$textbox = $('#searchbox');
$body = $('body').filter(':first');
$places = $('#resultsListing li.place');

$textbox.keyup(function() {
    if($(this).val() == '') $body.addClass('hasnt-typed-yet');
    else $body.removeClass('hasnt-typed-yet');
});

$body.addClass($places.length > 0 ? 'have-results' : 'no-results');
$('#busyAnimation').hide();
```